# Google Sheets – "Repeat with each"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out a formula to skip (completely avoid) column D. I need some kind of "repeat with each" setup.

Each row is multiplied and then the columns are added up.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NFdIdSPQib0XK14zssG6I3mDlc0WUmK6uQMNlrWsfw0/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
= SUMPRODUCT(B3:B6;C3:C6)
```

---

### Reference:

- [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)

---